# Loading a plugin with Firebreath and Curl

Tags: c++, curl, firebreath

I'm building a plugin using Firebreath and Linux [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/). I get the following errors when i tried to load my plugin in another Linux system (Ubuntu 11.10).

```
[3957:3957:162659560325:ERROR:plugin_list.cc(448)] Loading plugin /home/admin/Documents/myplugin/0.1/npMediaDownload.so
[3957:3957:162659561719:ERROR:plugin_lib_posix.cc(158)] While reading plugin info, unable to load library /home/admin/Documents/myplugin/0.1/npMediaDownload.so (/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by /home/admin/Documents/myplugin/0.1/npMediaDownload.so)), skipping.
```

I already have the `#include "curl/curl.h"` on my MediaDownloadAPI.cpp. In my project folder i added the following:

**X11/projectDef.cmake**

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PLUGIN_INTERNAL_DEPS} curl )
```

**PluginConfig.cmake**

```
add_firebreath_library(curl)
```

I haven't problem to compile and execute the plugin on Arch Linux system.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because Openssl versions. In Arch linux Openssl version 4 and over Ubuntu 12.04 version 3. I tried adding `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);` to my program but that not solves the problem. I will mark this as solved because i know what the problem is but not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is that you're linking against a dynamic (.so) version of curl and the system you're trying to load it on is lacking that library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I encountered several problems to static link Curl, there are many dependencies :(. Is there a way to get the HTTP header without using cURL, something similar to this: [Shows how to access the HTTP headers from a given web adress.](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/get-http-header.htm)?

Comment: you could use SimpleStreamsHelper::AsyncGet.  There is an example of how to do it in FBTestPlugin. You get the headers as part of the response. I don't know if it's possible with Browser Streams to get the header only.

Comment: ohhh, looks like a Openssl version problem. I tried with a Ubuntu (12.04) and Debian system and it works as expected. Both works with Openssl version 3. I tried to run my program adding `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);` compiled on Arch linux system and then running on Ubuntu and still no luck. I will open a new question with that issue. Anyway, thanks alot for your comment @taxilian.